# MySQL: Select row order by date with group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_wallet
WHERE credit_balance<0
GROUP BY cus_id
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

It should give me last added detail by means of cus_id with credit_balance<0. But, it's giving me first negative balance one.

It will work if I will remove `GROUP BY` from my query. But, I need to keep that as all the customers are in same table.

This is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eed909/2).

credit_balance should be -50. Not -111.

Comment: I suppose you don't understand how group by works, do you want all latest transactions for each user?

Comment: yes. with `credit_balance<0`

Comment: SELECT * FROM customer_wallet ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is proper query:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer_wallet as a
inner join
(
  select max(id) as maxid
  from customer_wallet
  WHERE credit_balance<0
  group by cus_id
) as b
on (a.id=b.maxid)
```

note: this query works because usually data inserted incrementally and we can assume that we can use id instead of date

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. For one, try the following:

```
SELECT cw.*
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM customer_wallet 
  WHERE credit_balance < 0
  ORDER BY date_added DESC
) cw
GROUP BY cw.cus_id;
```

You could also use a MAX() on date_added:

```
SELECT credit_balance, date_added
FROM customer_wallet
WHERE credit_balance < 0
GROUP BY cus_id
ORDER BY MAX(date_added) DESC;
```

Either of those should work for you.